# How to get header name (colNames) from data base in jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

I have two tables that joined. I get data from this query and show in jqgrid.
In normality my grid like this:

[image]

I want to show first column (C02/ C01 /C01/ C02 /C01) like header(colNames) and second column (2.2.2.2 /  1.1.1  /1.1.1 / 8.8.8.8. /  6.6.6.6) for value of first column and for other column like second column and sit below header. Indeed i'm gonna change horizontal grid to vertical(I think). My jqGrid code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var searchOptions = ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'bw', 'bn', 'in', 'ni', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc'];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#list').jqGrid({
        caption: "ObisData",
        //url from wich data should be requested
        url: '@Url.Action("GetObisData", "DataGrid")',
        //EditData
        editurl: '@Url.Action("EditData", "DataGrid")',
        //type of data
        datatype: 'json',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "Rows",
            page: "Page",
            total: "Total",
            records: "Records",
            repeatitems: true,
            id: "ObisDataID",
            cell: "RowCells"
        },
        //url access method type
        mtype: 'POST',
        //columns names
        colNames: [ '', '', '', ''],
        //columns model
        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'ObisDataID', index: 'ObisDataID', align: 'right', width: 100,
                editable: false, hidden: true, key: true

            },
        {
            name: 'ObisInfoTitle', index: 'ObisInfoTitle', align: 'center', width: 100,
            editable: false, hidden: false

        }
        ,

        {
            name: 'ObisData', index: 'ObisData', align: 'center', width: 100,
            editable: false, hidden: false
        }
        ,
        {
            name: 'ObisInfoTranslateT', index: 'ObisInfoTranslateT', align: 'center', width: 170,
            editable: false, hidden: false
        }

        ],
        //pager for grid
        pager: $('#pager'),
        //number of rows per page
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
        //initial sorting column
        sortname: 'ObisDataID',
        //initial sorting direction
        sortorder: 'desc',
        //we want to display total records count
        viewrecords: true,
        altRows: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        width: '1100',
        height: 'auto',
        hidegrid: false,
        direction: "rtl",
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        footerrow: true,
        //userDataOnFooter: true,
        loadComplete: function () {
            //change alternate rows color
            $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#E0E0E0");
        },
        loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
            jQuery("#rsperror").html("Type: " + st + "; Response: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
        //, loadonce: true
    })
```

Comment: Can you add jqgrid code.....

Comment: @Krishnakumar Subbaiyan yes. I edited my question.

Comment: @KrishnakumarSubbaiyan does need to add controller?

Answer (score 0):

Change the direction code. then your grid will align left to right

```
direction : "ltr"
```

You don't want row numbers to

```
rownumbers: false
```

**Header names From DB**

First assign DB value in js variable after you will add colNames in jqgrid code.

```
var firstColName={insert DBvalue data};
var secondColName={insert DBvalue data};
var thirdColName={insert DBvalue data};

 colNames: [ firstColName, secondColName,thirdColName, ......],
```

Comment: @Krishnakumr Subbaiyan I mean first column be header an other column be value of header. i want to have vertical grid. in header sit C01 C02 ...... and in first row below header sit 2.2.2.2   1.1.1 ,............

Comment: but i don,t know how much there is data for header. because I get this with join two tables.

Comment: Thanks for reply. where i use (var firstColName={insert DBvalue data};) and what's DBvalue?

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli Jqgrid you can use column values as column value only, my opinion for your question, You have modify the value in backend. based on column and row for jqgrid. its difficult do for in front end.

Comment: @Oleg I'm sorry to disturb you. I have a question. Can i use pivot property for jqgrid? I want to change horizontal grid to vertical . please if possible help me. Thanks you very much